# Question on algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality

Can somebody please help me in proving/disproving the following?

Let $v_i>0, \overset{n}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}}a_i^2=\overset{m}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}}b_i^2=1$ and $ \overset{n}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}}a_i=\overset{m}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}}b_i=0$.

Then, is it always possible to have $\overset{n}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}} a_i^2v_i\geq \overset{m}{\underset{i =1}{\sum}} b_i^2v_i$, with $m<n$?

Note that when $v_i$ are identical, then both sums are equal. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the inequality, should it be $b_i$ instead of $a_i$ on the right side?

Comment: "is it possible"? Yes, it is possible for specially selected values of $ a_i, b_i, v_i$. Are you wanting to ask "must we always have" instead?

Comment: @MaoWao yes,edited.

Comment: @Calvin Lin, yes I am asking for always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, we construct a sequence of numbers: $ b'_i $ for $ i = 1,...,n $
$$ b'_i = b_i \,(\text{when }i \leq m) \; b'_i = 0 \,(\text{when }n \geq i > m) $$
then, we know that $$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} b'_i = 0 $$
and $$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {b'}_{i}^{2} = 1 $$
Notice that $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2}v_i $ and $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} b_{i}^{2}v_i $ are equivalent to the original LHS and RHS of the inequality. They have the same structure. Thus, the order cannot be determined.

Even if all the $a_i$'s are non-zero, the inequality does not hold. Since $v_i$'s can be arbitrarily given, we first determine the value of $a_i $ and $ b_i $. Now, we claim that
$$ \exists j\text{      s.t. } |a_j| < |b_j| $$
Based on this discovery, we can assign an arbitrarily large $ v_j $, and arbitrarily small $ v_i \,(i \neq j) $. In this way, we can make the inequality reversed.

Comment: thanks. I think $v_i$ controls everything here. I meant given arbitrary sequence of $a_i$ and $b_i$ (as per restrictions), the inequality can be made true as well by assigning $v_i$ accordingly. Isn't it?

Comment: If you meant this, we can assign large values to $ v_i $'s if $ i > m $, and small values to others to complete the proof.

Comment: Right.  If we consider $v_i$ arbitrary, is it possible to make this inequality true by control over $ a_i$ and $b_i$? From little calculation(considering both sums one side), if we show that ($a_i^2-b_i^2), $ i =1,2,...,m$ is positive or arbitrary small for some sequences  then this inequality hold true. Geometrically, let me tell you that the vector a=(a_1,...a_n) and b=(b_1,...,b_m) are unit vectors and their components' sums are zero. If you have any idea how to get these vectors so that inequality holds, please share.

Comment: I doubt it. Here is my point. Let's think about such $v_i$'s that $v_i = c$ when $ i \leq 2 = m $,  and $v_i = \epsilon $ when $ i = m+1,...,n $, where $ c>>\epsilon $. Then, RHS is always $ c $. Due to $a_i \neq 0 $, however, the increment of LHS caused by $a_3, a_4,...$ cannot compensate the decay of $a_1, a_2$. I wonder if this is obvious by the derivative of $ y = x^2 $ around $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

Comment: Here is a more concrete counterexample: For $ m = 2 $ and $ n = 3 $, $ v_1 = v_2 = 100 $, and $ v_3 = 0.5 $. You have no way to make the inequality hold.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.